# How to prove that this sequence is divergent? Problem with a limit

Tags: calculus, limits, power-series

I'm trying to calculate the interval of convergence and the values of x in which the series converge absolutely and conditionally

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(1+\frac{1}{\:n}\right)^nx^n$

My attempt:
First I calculated the interval of convergence $-1<x<1$, using the root test. 
Then, I looked for the convergence in $x=1$ and $x=-1$

With $x=1$ it was easy: the limit is $e$ so it's divergent in that point. 
But with $x=-1$ it's more difficult, because we have

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(1+\frac{1}{\:n}\right)^n(-1)^n$

And I don't know how to proceed... First I tried using the limit... I wasn't sure how so I tried to insert it on symbolab but I don't understand why:

$\lim _{m\to \infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{\:2m+1}\right)^{2m+1}(-1)^{2m+1} = - 1$

Shouldn't this limit, by substitution, be equal to $-e$

Can someone please help me to compute this limit OR to find a better process to test the convergence in $x=-1$?

Comment: You're right, the last limit you compute should be $-e$, by the way. What did you type in Symbolab? Is there any chance you made a typo and looked for the limit of $$\left(1+\frac{1}{(2m+1)^{2m+1}}\right)(-1)^{2m+1}$$ instead?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\lim_{n->\infty} \left(1+ {1\over n}\right)^n (-1)^n$ does not converge to 0, the series does not converge for $x = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Does the sequence $a_n=(-1)^n (1+\frac1n)^n$ converge to zero? Note that a *necessary* criterion for the series $\sum a_n$ to converge is that $a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$.

More:

> The result above is because, if $A_N=\sum_{n=0}^N a_n$ converges to $\ell$ when $N\to\infty$, then $a_N =A_N - A_{N-1} \to \ell -\ell = 0$.
>  But here, $\lvert a_n\rvert \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e > 0$.

Comment: Rk: Place your mouse on the gray area to reveal the contents.